# HTML Link to Execute Javascript Function after 3 clicks

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there is a way to execute a javascript function only if the user clicks the link for 3 times.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a onclick="toggleFullScreen()">Toggle Fullscreen</a>
```

And here is the Javascript part:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `event.detail` ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Properties)) which is used by the browser to store the count of consecutive clicks that happened in a short amount of time. Here's a minimal example of logging to the console when the user triple-clicks anywhere:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.detail === 3) {
        console.log('triple click');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can this work when there is a delay between clicks?

Comment: @horia It will only trigger if the clicks are close to each other, much like a double click, except the user clicks three times. If there is a larger delay, it will not count.

Answer (score 2):

Use local storage for a global variable. See this article, it even has an example to count clicks: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: While this is a working solution, there are more modern ways that do not involve local storage for this kind of thing. I am only mentioning this because using local storage can come with its own caveats and/or limitations.